# install job on crontab

Tags: centos, cron

I definitely sure that the syntax I am using in the crontab file is correct because I installed the same job on another host and it is working fine.
The syntax is:

```
05 10 * * mon,wed,fri /app/aban/scripts/remove_log.sh >> /app/aban/scripts/remove.log 2>&1
```

Also, I tried this one:

```
* * * * * /app/aban/scripts/remove_log.sh
```

the error is :

```
crontab: installing new crontabempty one
"/tmp/crontab.fuqF5D":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.fuqF5D
```

Please note that I have logged in as 'aban' user. I can install cronjobs on other hosts with the same user logged in.

Any advice?

Comment: The particular cron daemon that you are using on the host may dislike the zero in `05`.  Try changing it to just `5`.  What cron daemon variant does your two hosts run?

Comment: if I get your mean right, its crond.service deamon

Comment: Is that the only line in the crontab ? Could the error be referring to another line?